# private constructor, subclassing and sealed

Tags: c#, constructor, subclass, sealed

If one can prevent subclassing by declaring private constructor in the base class, why do we need "sealed" keyword? Is it so because CLI can optimize it better? maybe.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you might want to have public constructors but not allow anyone to derive from your class

Comment: Certainly. There are loads of examples, of course, but to mention one, `string` (also known as `System.String`) has many `public` instance constructors, but you can't derive from it because it is `sealed`. For an example where the (only) instance constructor is `internal`, see `System.CharEnumerator`.

Comment: why you want to do such that?

Answer (score 2):

If a class is sealed some optimizations can be performed. i.e. the clr could emit .call instruction rather than a .callvirt